# What kind of statements don't require semicolon termination in C++?

Tags: c++, parsing, syntax, grammar

Is there a rule regarding which statements don't need to be terminated with a semicolon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's covered in section 6, "Statement" of the C++ standard (section 6 of C++03, it may have changed in C++11 but I don't have access to that one at the moment).

There are a large number of statement types and not all of them need to be terminated. For example, the following `if` is a selection statement:

```
if (i == 1) {
    doSomething();
}
```

and there is *no* requirement to terminate that with a semi-colon.

Of the different statements covered, the requirements are:

```
Statement type        Termination required?
==============        =====================
labelled statement              N (a)
expression                      Y
compound statements             N (a)
selection statements            N (a)
iteration statements            N (a) (b)
jump statements                 Y
declaration statement           Y
```

(a) Although it may sometimes *appear* that these are terminated with a semi-colon, that's not the case. The statement:

```
if (i == 1) doSomething();
```

has the semi-colon terminating the *inner* expression statement, not the compound statement, somthing that should be obvious when you examine the first code segment above that has it inside `{}` braces.

(b) `do` requires the semi-colon after the `while` expression.

Answer (score 3):

Block statements do not need to have semicolons after them, which is why we don't need a semicolon after the close brace in this code:

```
while (true) {
    cout << "Hi!" << endl;
}
```

Any expression acting as a statement must have a semicolon after it, which is why the `cout` line above is terminated with a semicolon.

Control statements (`if`, `do`, `while`, `switch`, etc.) do not need a semicolon after them, except for `do ... while`, must have a semicolon after it.  However, if the statement that they control ends with a semicolon, the overall statement itself will.  For example:

```
while (true) cout << "Are we there yet?" << endl;
```

ends with a semicolon, because the controlled `cout` statement ends with a semicolon.

Control-flow changing statements like `break`, `continue`, `goto`, `return`, and `throw` must have semicolons after them.

Declaration statements like function prototypes, variable declarations, and struct/class/union declarations must be terminated with semicolons.

For a complete list of statement types and their syntax, you can check out §6 of the C++ ISO standard, which goes over the grammars for each of these types of statements.  This is how I was able to compile this list.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

1. MACRO definitions don't require either.
2. All keywords(such as if,else,for,while,do,main) after brackets open and then close ,don't require semicolons as previously stated.

3.After these indentifiers void,int,string,long etc..no semicolons required.

4.Functions also don't need semicolons when definitons come along.

such as void fun(){........}

Comment: (1) Macro definitions aren't statements. (2) `main` is not a keyword. (3) these identifiers (typenames) appear in many contexts, including inside statements. There is no relation between these typenames appearing in statements and the need for semicolons. (4) Function definitions aren't statements either.